# Question on split function on a text field

Tags: split

I need your help in splitting the following text.

Here is the text field :  - 'Lead id of this field ref:_x12rftf001265qr.dt50:ref'

How I can split this text to get only  this text  'ref:_x12rftf001265qr.dt50:ref'

Thanks in advance 
Raj

Comment: can u pls share ur current code and say what options you tried and where you are stuck ?

Comment: Here is the subject line of my email message :   

Sandbox: Geico Case #00011285: test [] ref:_00Dq0i0h._500m04fISN:ref    from this subject line, I need       'ref:_xxxxx:ref '

Answer (score 0):

`String s1 = 'Sandbox: Geico Case #00011285: test [] ref:_00Dq0i0h._500m04fISN:ref';
String s2 = s1.substringAfterLast(' ');`

This will work only if you ref id is always at the end and is separated by space. You can [find more string methods here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm).

Answer (score 0):

`String s1 = 'Sandbox: Geico Case #00011285: test [] ref:_00Dq0i0h._500m04fISN:ref';
 String s2 = s1.substring(s1.indexOf('ref'),s1.length());`

This will extract the required text from the place where first occurrence of 'ref' is found till the end of the text.So no need to worry about the spaces in text.